# Animation of SVG doesnt work

Tags: animation, svg

i have a challenge with SVG-Code and i can't get the result i want to have.

I want the opposite of the row_five. 
The row should extend from the bottom to the top.

Code:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216);">
<rect x="00" y="90" width="20" height="10" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216);" id="row_one"/>
<rect x="30" y="70" width="20" height="30" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216);" id="row_two"/>
<rect x="60" y="50" width="20" height="50" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216);" id="row_three"/>
<rect x="90" y="30" width="20" height="70" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216);" id="row_four"/>
<rect x="120" y="10" width="20" height="90" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216);" id="row_five">
    <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="90" begin= "0s" dur="1s"/>
</rect> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Animate the y at the same time as the height.

Comment: You mean something like this? `<rect x="120" y="10" width="20" height="90" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216);" id="row_five"> <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="90" begin= "0s" dur="1s"/> <animate attributeName="<" from="0" to="10" begin= "0s" dur="1s"/> </rect> ` That has the same results as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Robert said, as you grow the height, you move the Y position.  (0,0) in SVG files is at the top left. So you actually need to *decrease* Y, not increase it.

Your fifth bar starts at y=10 and has a height of 90. So the bottom of the bar is at y=100. So you need to animate `y` from 100 down to 10.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216);">
<rect x="00" y="90" width="20" height="10" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216);" id="row_one"/>
<rect x="30" y="70" width="20" height="30" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216);" id="row_two"/>
<rect x="60" y="50" width="20" height="50" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216);" id="row_three"/>
<rect x="90" y="30" width="20" height="70" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216);" id="row_four"/>
<rect x="120" y="10" width="20" height="90" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216);" id="row_five">
    <animate attributeName="y" from="100" to="10" begin= "0s" dur="1s"/>
    <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="90" begin= "0s" dur="1s"/>
</rect> 
</svg>
```